# Bing Maps - Determine max zoom level for static aerial map with REST imagery API

Tags: bing-maps

I am retrieving a static aerial map from Bing maps via the REST imagery API.  Some geographic areas seem to support a greater zoom level than other areas.

For example, this location supports a zoom level up to 21: http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Aerial/33.049101,-96.822731/21?key=someKey

But this location seems to max out at 19: http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Aerial/38.82716,-97.6352/19?key=someKey

If a zoom level of 19 is exceeded, an image is returned but the image contains nothing more than a camera with a slash through it, indicating that the maximum zoom level has been exceeded.

Is there a way to call the API to determine the maximum zoom that will return a valid aerial image?

Thanks,
Skip

Comment: Technicaly, you would be able to get metadata (with min and max zoom) for a specific point with URI like this: http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Metadata/Aerial/33.049101,-96.822731?zl=19&o=xml&key=YOURKEY

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly Bing does not seem to offer this feature directly. I would have expected the Imagery Metadata response to include a field which indicates the highest zoom level which will return valid imagery at that location. However, zoomMin and zoomMax seem to be basically useless. Often you will notice that imagery at zoomMax will return a "broken" image, and actual imagery is only available at a lower zoom level.

I have created a workaround that seems to work quite well. It seems that the vintageStart (and vintageEnd) fields are populated with values (e.g. "31 Jan 2006 GMT") when imagery actually exists at the zoom level which you specify in the Imagery Metadata request url. When real imagery is not available vintageStart and vintageEnd seem to be set to null. (I wonder if this is absolutely reliable?)

You can start at level 21 and work down the zoom levels. The first level which has vintageStart populated can be assumed to be the best available zoom level with valid imagery.

**Depth 21: vintageStart is null**
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Metadata/Aerial/40.714550167322159,-74.007124900817871?zl=21&key=BING_API_KEY

Notice that maxZoom says 21 but you will see this does not have valid imagery.

**Depth 21: Broken Image**
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/aerial/40.714550167322159,-74.007124900817871/21?key=BING_API_KEY

**Depth 20: vintageStart is populated**
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Metadata/Aerial/40.714550167322159,-74.007124900817871?zl=20&key=BING_API_KEY

**Depth 20: Valid Image** :-)
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/aerial/40.714550167322159,-74.007124900817871/20?key=BING_API_KEY

### Sample code in PHP...

```
function getHighestZoomAtLocation($lon, $lat){

    //Add extra zoom levels to check if necessary
    foreach(array(21, 20, 19, 18) as $zoom){

        $url = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Metadata/Aerial/{$lat},{$lon}?&zoomLevel={$zoom}&key=BING_API_KEY";

        $imagery_meta_data_raw = file_get_contents($url);

        $imagery_meta_data = json_decode($imagery_meta_data_raw, true);

        if(!empty($imagery_meta_data['resourceSets'][0]['resources'][0]['imageUrl']) && !empty($imagery_meta_data['resourceSets'][0]['resources'][0]['vintageStart'])){
            return $zoom;
        }

    }

    return false;

}
```

(Note that this approach may burn through your transaction quota if used extensively)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Nicolas, you can get the zoom range of an area of the map using the Bing Maps Imagery Metadata REST service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701716.aspx